# Reseeding C# Random instance

Tags: c#, random, random-seed

I have a `Random` instance in my C# project which I instantiated with a seed.

```cs
private Random randomInt = new Random(1234);
```

I want to do reseed the same instance without creating new `Random` instances.

```cs
randomInt.Reseed(5678);
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Or should I just create a new instance?

Comment: Why are you against creating a new instance? How often are you doing this?

Comment: First, there's no `Reseed()` method in `Random` class, second, why not creating a new instance, and third why do you want to reseed anyway?

Comment: don't under estimate power of Garbage collectors. they are created exactly for these scenarios so you don't have to think too hard :)

Comment: @John Just trying to avoid heap work. Because I have to reset the seed multiple times to the same seed. So a way to reseed or reset would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you need to repeat the same values, why don't you store them somewhere?

Comment: There is not even a way to `reset` the random generator. so if you want to start over with same seed you have to create new instance. Random class is cheap to initialize.

Comment: I am procedurally generating game worlds. I just need to perform a several Random.Next(int,int) operations exactly the same for a particular seed. So that I only have to store the seed in the game save files.

Comment: If you want to use the same see, the output numbers are already known from the last seed(if you use the same seed), you can store in RAM the results and use them if you dont create a new `Random` instacne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the [members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2) in `Random` allows you to change the seed, you have to create a new instance.